# Finding boundary pixels with Opencv without for loop

Tags: python, image, opencv, processing, pixel

I am trying to find boundary pixels of foreground object from binary image without using for loop. If anyone of the four neighbor of the specific pixel coordinate is zero and that pixel value is one, I will assign it as a boundary pixel. It works fine with for loop but I don't want to use a loop so is there anything I can do with it. Here is the code:

```py
for i in range(len(PCR)):
    cr_h = PCR[i,0]
    cr_w = PCR[i,1]
    n1 = img_cap_copy[cr_h-1,cr_w]
    n2 = img_cap_copy[cr_h+1,cr_w]
    n3 = img_cap_copy[cr_h,cr_w-1]
    n4 = img_cap_copy[cr_h,cr_w+1]
    n=[n1,n2,n3,n4]
    if img_cap_copy[cr_h,cr_w]==1 and (n[0]==0 or n[1]==0 or n[2]==0 or n[3]==0):
        Xc.append(cr_w)
        Yc.append(cr_h)
```

This is what I am trying to do without for loop which is giving me error'The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all().'

```py
cr_h=PCR[:,0]
cr_h=PCR[:,0]
n1 = img_cap_copy[cr_h-1,cr_w]
n2 = img_cap_copy[cr_h+1,cr_w]
n3 = img_cap_copy[cr_h,cr_w-1]
n4 = img_cap_copy[cr_h,cr_w+1]
n=[n1,n2,n3,n4]
if img_cap_copy[cr_h,cr_w]==1 and (n[0]==0 or n[1]==0 or n[2]==0 or n[3]==0):
    Xc.append(cr_w)
    Yc.append(cr_h)
```

Comment: Post an example image to some free hosting service and put the URL. Then define boundary pixels!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use `np.logical_or` and `np.logical_and` and logical indexing as follows:

```
cr_h=PCR[:,0]
cr_w=PCR[:,1] #cr_h=PCR[:,0]
n1 = img_cap_copy[cr_h-1,cr_w]
n2 = img_cap_copy[cr_h+1,cr_w]
n3 = img_cap_copy[cr_h,cr_w-1]
n4 = img_cap_copy[cr_h,cr_w+1]

# Logical array with True where condition is met
c = np.logical_and(img_cap_copy[cr_h,cr_w]==1, np.logical_or(np.logical_or(np.logical_or(n1==0, n2==0), n3==0), n4==0))

# Use logical indexing - return elements when c is True.
Xc = cr_w[c].tolist()
Yc = cr_h[c].tolist()
```

---

Testing code:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

# Build sample image
img = np.random.randint(0, 255, (120, 160), np.uint8)
img_cap_copy = np.minimum(cv2.threshold(img, 50, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)[1], 1)

# Build sample PRC
PCR = np.vstack((np.r_[1:1001], np.r_[10:1010])).T % 100

# Used as reference
refXc = []
refYc = []

for i in range(len(PCR)):
    cr_h = PCR[i,0]
    cr_w = PCR[i,1]
    n1 = img_cap_copy[cr_h-1,cr_w]
    n2 = img_cap_copy[cr_h+1,cr_w]
    n3 = img_cap_copy[cr_h,cr_w-1]
    n4 = img_cap_copy[cr_h,cr_w+1]
    n=[n1,n2,n3,n4]
    if img_cap_copy[cr_h,cr_w]==1 and (n[0]==0 or n[1]==0 or n[2]==0 or n[3]==0):
        refXc.append(cr_w)
        refYc.append(cr_h)


cr_h=PCR[:,0]
cr_w=PCR[:,1] #cr_h=PCR[:,0]
n1 = img_cap_copy[cr_h-1,cr_w]
n2 = img_cap_copy[cr_h+1,cr_w]
n3 = img_cap_copy[cr_h,cr_w-1]
n4 = img_cap_copy[cr_h,cr_w+1]

# Logical array with True where condition is met
c = np.logical_and(img_cap_copy[cr_h,cr_w]==1, np.logical_or(np.logical_or(np.logical_or(n1==0, n2==0), n3==0), n4==0))

# Use logical indexing - return elements when c is True.
Xc = cr_w[c].tolist()
Yc = cr_h[c].tolist()

print(str(np.all(np.array(Xc) == np.array(refXc))))
print(str(np.all(np.array(Yc) == np.array(refYc))))
```

---

Note:

- In case `img_cap_copy` has only ones and zeros, you may use math instead of logical operations, but using `np.logical_or` and `np.logical_and` is closer to your original loop code.

Comment: Thank you so much. About using math instead of logical operations, could you please tell me how it is true that img_cap_copy only contains one and zero.

Comment: You can use binary and `and` and `or` for example: `c = (img_cap_copy[cr_h,cr_w] & ((n1 & n2 & n3 & n4) ^ 1)) != 0`.  Or multiplication and subtraction: `c = (img_cap_copy[cr_h,cr_w] * (1 - (n1 * n2 * n3 * n4))) != 0`